# Apache Ant: How to execute batch file on windows remote system

Tags: windows, ant

Apache Ant: How to execute batch file on windows remote system

I want to execute a batch file on remote system having windows os

Whats the easiest way to execute a batch on remote system using ant scripts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try the sshexec task.

http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/sshexec.html

Comment: Of course you'd to install an SSH server on the remote windows machine for this to work